# Symfony 2 schema update fails on changing primary key datatype from integer to Bigint

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a users table with column id as primary key. I am referencing this column in several other tables. Now i want change the users table id column's datatype to Bigint. So, i changed 'integer' to 'bigint' and generated entities successfully. But if i try to update the schema it is getting failed. Please suggest on this.

main table(users) yml:

```
table: users
id:
    id:
        type: bigint
        generator: { strategy: AUTO }
```

Example Referencing table(user_profiles) yml:

```
oneToOne:
    user_id:
      targetEntity: Users
      inversedBy: userprofile
      joinColumn:
        name: user_id
        referencedColumnName: id
```

Error on

> php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force
>
> [Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\DriverException]
>    An exception occurred while executing 'ALTER TABLE user_claim A
>    DD CONSTRAINT FK_CDFFA2C4A76ED395 FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users (id)':
>    SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint

I have tried to `SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;` in MySql command prompt also. But no use.

Comment: Is there any option to update the schema with no foreign key checks ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to update foreign key columns in other tables to same type as ID (`bigint`).

Take a look at: [Setting up foreign key with different datatype](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32267778/setting-up-foreign-key-with-different-datatype)

Comment: But in symfony2 framework we can only reference the join column with table name only. we cannot explicitly add datatype to foreign key columns.

Comment: Update those columns manually via sql statements. No one is forcing you to do everything through doctrine. If you need to push those changes to remote setup take a look at phinx for example https://phinx.org/