# How to map Character and Integer Columns in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

Currently i have two tables

- `userdetails`
- `userid_bankid`

Both are mapped with column **userId** , **userId** in first table is Integer and second table is charterer.

```
@JoinColumn(name = "userId",referencedColumnName="userId" nullable = false , insertable = false, updatable = false)
```

i am getting typecast error

Comment: The foreign key of one table has to be the same type as its corresponding primary key in the other table. A single character can not map all the user id integer values. Can you update the design of your tables?

Comment: its already working , i should be Integer but one place it was character

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3096985/jpa-or-hibernate-joining-tables-on-columns-of-different-types) I think this might solve your problem or help you to solve your problem.

Comment: can you explain more

Comment: I think @khary Mendez's comment is right. Initially the foreign key and primary key should have same datatype. In support of my comment there are two references.
1. [Stackoverflow's](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32267778/setting-up-foreign-key-with-different-datatype).
2. [Mysql syntax](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=30875&seqNum=8)

I think that you should update your database design.

Comment: now trying to update db design ,now i am doing a code update

Comment: Yeah sure, you could reference to the link given in my answer. There are some useful statements and answers on that stackoverflow's question like 
[Column and formula elements](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/mapping.html#mapping-column)

Comment: Just upvote any comment which satisfied your query. Or accept the answer which did the same.