# Why should my FK column and the referenced column have the same type?

Tags: database, postgresql, integer, foreign-keys, bigint

Assume I have two tables that share a relation:

1. posts
2. comments

My `posts` table has an `id` column of type `bigint` and my `comments.post_id` foreign key is of type `integer`.

What could go wrong?  Why is it recommended that `comments.post_id` also be of the type `bigint`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting up foreign key with different datatype](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32267778/setting-up-foreign-key-with-different-datatype)

Comment: Hi. What do you think a FK is? The *definition* of a (SQL) FK is a list of columns whose subrow values appear elsewhere as PK/UNIQUE. Since a bigint can be out of range for an integer, how could that be? The bigint column would have to be limited to integer range. So why aren't you declaring it integer? PS Please always google many clear, concise & specific versions/phrasings of your question/problem/goal with & without your particular strings/names & read many answers. If you don't find an answer then post, using use one variant search for your title & keywords for your tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Big int can be as large as 9,223,372,036,854,775,807, while int only goes to 2,147,483,647. Therefore, if your data grows large enough to surpass 2,147,483,647 like 2,147,483,648 for example, you would no longer be able to reference your post in your comments.post_id column.

Comment: This makes total sense. Should the DB throw a warning or something if there's a type mismatch? I have tried this with Postgres and my relations work fine. I suppose it would fail silently.

Comment: @BillyBlobSnortin Do not suppose. *Read the documentation.* The DBMS designers could decide to allow the static mismatch of obviously coercible numerical types as long as the values in the table satisfy the constraint--that all the bigints are in integer range. (Such a decision could be considered a convenience and/or a pitfall.)

Comment: No, the DBMS will throw an error. ORA-12899 for SQL Server for example.

Answer (score 0):

Well , from a database perspective , If the user using your database inserted a `bigint` which was present in your main relation and your relation refused it because the data type doesn't match (and by that I mean cases where your entry is larger than the `int` datatype) ,
then you have committed a logical error , because that entry should have been accepted as it satisfies the **FK** constraint .